# How to implement datatable xbl control to Orbeon Form Builder Xform

Tags: datatable, xforms, xbl, orbeon

I am new to xforms - using Orbeon Form Builder 3.8 PE.  I have read about advanced xbl controls like 'Alert Dialog' and 'Datatable'.  These would be very useful in my application, but I cannot bridge my knowledge gap as to how to implement them.

It seems either I need to add a property somewhere to get them in the toolbox; or I need to directly add code to the xform. The Orbeon examples show snippets whic lead me to think it's the latter/  However, the examples are out of context - no idea which tags are used to sandwich these things or how to refer to them later in actions and such.

Thanks in advance.  [EDIT: Code below per comment]
Bill

```
<xhtml:html xmlns:xhtml="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
        xmlns:xxi="http://orbeon.org/oxf/xml/xinclude"
        xmlns:xxforms="http://orbeon.org/oxf/xml/xforms"
        xmlns:exforms="http://www.exforms.org/exf/1-0"
        xmlns:fr="http://orbeon.org/oxf/xml/form-runner"
        xmlns:saxon="http://saxon.sf.net/"
        xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
        xmlns:oxf="http://www.orbeon.com/oxf/processors"
        xmlns:sql="http://orbeon.org/oxf/xml/sql"
        xmlns:xi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XInclude"
        xmlns:ev="http://www.w3.org/2001/xml-events"
        xmlns:xforms="http://www.w3.org/2002/xforms"
        xmlns:pipeline="java:org.orbeon.oxf.processor.pipeline.PipelineFunctionLibrary"
        xmlns:p="http://www.orbeon.com/oxf/pipeline"
        xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
        xmlns:odt="http://orbeon.org/oxf/xml/datatypes"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<xhtml:head>
    <xhtml:title>Operations</xhtml:title>
    <xforms:model id="fr-form-model">


        <xforms:instance id="fr-form-instance">
            <form>
                <section-1>
                    <control-1/>
                    <control-2/>
                </section-1>
                <section-2/>
                    <control-3/>
            </form>
        </xforms:instance>


        <xforms:bind id="fr-form-binds" nodeset="instance('fr-form-instance')">
            <xforms:bind id="section-1-bind" nodeset="section-1">
                <xforms:bind id="control-1-bind" name="control-1" nodeset="control-1"/>
                <xforms:bind id="control-2-bind" name="control-2" nodeset="control-2"/>
            </xforms:bind>
            <xforms:bind id="section-2-bind" nodeset="section-2">
                <xforms:bind id="control-3-bind" name="control-3" nodeset="control-3"/>
            </xforms:bind>
        </xforms:bind>


        <xforms:instance id="fr-form-metadata" xxforms:readonly="true">
            <metadata>
                <application-name>KENAN_TOOLKIT</application-name>
                <form-name>operations-process</form-name>
                <title xml:lang="en">Operations</title>
                <description xml:lang="en"/>
                <author/>
                <logo mediatype="image/jpeg" filename="optimum-lightpath-logo-810x141.JPG"
                      size="14799">/fr/service/oracle/crud/orbeon/builder/data/3978eab19d9c6ccd8c65a787aa1864c4/541ca86ada859805464573ca539d6327.JPG</logo>
            </metadata>
        </xforms:instance>


        <xforms:instance id="fr-form-attachments">
            <attachments>
                <css mediatype="text/css" filename="" size=""/>
                <pdf mediatype="application/pdf" filename="" size=""/>
            </attachments>
        </xforms:instance>



        <xforms:instance id="fr-form-resources" xxforms:readonly="false">
            <resources>
                <resource xml:lang="en">
                    <section-1>
                        <label>EBF</label>
                        <help/>
                    </section-1>
                    <control-1>
                        <label/>
                        <hint/>
                        <help/>
                        <alert/>
                    </control-1>
                    <control-2>
                        <label/>
                        <hint/>
                        <help/>
                        <alert/>
                    </control-2>
                    <section-2>
                        <label>Archive</label>
                        <help/>
                    </section-2>
                    <control-3>
                        <label/>
                        <hint/>
                        <help/>
                        <alert/>
                    </control-3>
                </resource>
            </resources>
        </xforms:instance>


        <xforms:instance id="fr-service-request-instance" xxforms:exclude-result-prefixes="#all">
            <request/>
        </xforms:instance>

        <xforms:instance id="fr-service-response-instance" xxforms:exclude-result-prefixes="#all">
            <response/>
        </xforms:instance>
        <xforms:instance id="testsvc-instance" class="fr-database-service"
                         xxforms:exclude-result-prefixes="#all">
            <body>&lt;sql:config xmlns:sql="http://orbeon.org/oxf/xml/sql"&gt;
            &lt;sql:datasource&gt;orbeonedmDS&lt;/sql:datasource&gt;
&lt;sql:query&gt;SELECT n.node_id as id, n.node_name_tid as name, n.sw_ver as ver, m.model_name as model FROM techmgr.node n, techmgr.model m WHERE n.model_id = m.model_id  and rownum between 0 and 100&lt;/sql:query&gt;

        &lt;/sql:config&gt;</body>
        </xforms:instance>
        <xforms:submission id="testsvc-submission" class="fr-database-service"
                           ref="instance('fr-service-request-instance')"
                           resource="/fr/service/custom/orbeon/database"
                           method="post"
                           serialization="application/xml"
                           replace="instance"
                           instance="fr-service-response-instance"/>
        <xforms:action id="pop-test-binding">

            <xforms:action ev:event="xforms-ready" ev:observer="fr-form-model">

                <xforms:send submission="testsvc-submission"/>
            </xforms:action>

            <xforms:action ev:event="xforms-submit" ev:observer="testsvc-submission">

                <xxforms:variable name="request-instance-name" select="'testsvc-instance'" as="xs:string"/>

                <xforms:insert nodeset="instance('fr-service-request-instance')"
                               origin="saxon:parse(instance($request-instance-name))"/>


                <xforms:action context="instance('fr-service-request-instance')">

                </xforms:action>
            </xforms:action>

            <xforms:action ev:event="xforms-submit-done" ev:observer="testsvc-submission"
                           context="instance('fr-service-response-instance')">

            </xforms:action>
        </xforms:action>

    </xforms:model>
</xhtml:head>
<xhtml:body>
    <fr:view>
        <xforms:label ref="instance('fr-form-metadata')/title"/>
        <fr:body>
            <fr:section id="section-1-section" bind="section-1-bind">
                <xforms:label ref="$form-resources/section-1/label"/>
                <xforms:help ref="$form-resources/section-1/help"/>
                <fr:grid columns="2">
                    <xhtml:tr>
                        <xhtml:td>
                            <xforms:input id="control-1-control" bind="control-1-bind">
                                <xforms:label ref="$form-resources/control-1/label"/>
                                <xforms:hint ref="$form-resources/control-1/hint"/>
                                <xforms:help ref="$form-resources/control-1/help"/>
                                <xforms:alert ref="$fr-resources/detail/labels/alert"/>
                            </xforms:input>
                        </xhtml:td>
                        <xhtml:td/>
                    </xhtml:tr>
                    <xhtml:tr>
                        <xhtml:td>
                            <xforms:input id="control-2-control" bind="control-2-bind">
                                <xforms:label ref="$form-resources/control-2/label"/>
                                <xforms:hint ref="$form-resources/control-2/hint"/>
                                <xforms:help ref="$form-resources/control-2/help"/>
                                <xforms:alert ref="$fr-resources/detail/labels/alert"/>
                            </xforms:input>
                        </xhtml:td>
                        <xhtml:td/>
                    </xhtml:tr>

                </fr:grid>
            </fr:section>
            <fr:section id="section-2-section" bind="section-2-bind">
                <xforms:label ref="$form-resources/section-2/label"/>
                <xforms:help ref="$form-resources/section-2/help"/>
                <fr:grid columns="1">
                    <xhtml:tr>
                        <xhtml:td>
                            <fr:datatable scrollable="both" width="800px" height="500px">
                                <thead>
                                    <tr>
                                        <th fr:sortable="true" fr:resizeable="true">ID</th>
                                        <th fr:sortable="true" fr:resizeable="true">Name</th>
                                        <th fr:sortable="true" fr:resizeable="true">Version</th>
                                        <th fr:sortable="true" fr:resizeable="true">Model</th>
                                    </tr>
                                </thead>
                                <tbody>
                                 <xforms:repeat nodeset="/testsvc:response/testsvc:row"> 
                                  <tr>
                                   <td>
                                    <xf:output value=""/>
                                   </td>
                                   <td>
                                   </td>
                                   <td>
                                   </td>
                                   <td>
                                   </td>
                                  </tr>
                                 </xforms:repeat>
                                </tbody>
                           </fr:datatable>
                        </xhtml:td>
                    </xhtml:tr>
                </fr:grid>
            </fr:section>
        </fr:body>
    </fr:view>
</xhtml:body>
```

Comment: Research and experimentation - here is where I am:

Comment: I am editing the source following the example http://wiki.orbeon.com/forms/doc/developer-guide/xbl-components/datatable .  Goal is to use response from testsvc database service to populate datatable control-3.

When I insert the <xf:output /> line, Orbeon complains of improperly formed XML.  I will try to post the entire code somewhere here.

Comment: OK - replaced xf:output with xforms:output.  Compiled ok.  Now getting "Prefix testsvc has not been declared".

Comment: Does anyone else have experience with this?  Possibly using a different technology - ie hybrid between xforms and javascript - to display a table of data?

Answer (score 2):

The documentation about XBL you'll find on the wiki is geared towards people who write XForms by hand, and who would like to either [use XBL components](http://wiki.orbeon.com/forms/doc/developer-guide/xbl-components) or [write their own XBL component](http://wiki.orbeon.com/forms/doc/developer-guide/xbl-components-guide), rather than add XBL components to Form Builder.

This being said, you can certainly add XBL components to Form Builder, but that will require you to change the source of the components, and for some components, maybe even change Form Builder itself. This is a task for "advanced Orbeon Forms developers", but hey, who said you aren't one, or won't become one very quickly? Just to give you a few pointers:

1. XBL components added to the toolbox are referenced from the `oxf.fb.toolbox.group.*` properties. The default is defined in [`properties-form-builder.xml`](https://github.com/orbeon/orbeon-forms/blob/master/src/resources-packaged/config/properties-form-builder.xml) and you can override this in your own `properties-local.xml`.
2. To be usable in Form Builder, controls need to provide some metadata to Form Builder. See for instance how this is done for a [simple text field](https://github.com/orbeon/orbeon-forms/blob/master/src/resources/forms/orbeon/builder/xbl/text-controls.xbl#L38). And maybe the simplest example of an XBL component is the [`<fr:button>`](https://github.com/orbeon/orbeon-forms/blob/master/src/resources/forms/orbeon/builder/xbl/other-controls.xbl#L76).
3. If the component you have requires significant configuration, doesn't fit well into once cell of a form (e.g. [datatable](http://wiki.orbeon.com/forms/doc/developer-guide/xbl-components/datatable)), or isn't even designed to fit into one cell (e.g. [alert dialog](http://wiki.orbeon.com/forms/doc/developer-guide/xbl-components/alert-dialog)), changes, maybe significant ones, to Form Builder will be for sure required.

#### Ideas about supporting the Orbeon datatable in Form Builder

1. All the components we have currently in Form Builder are bound to one node that contains one value. Even a date/time control, which can show as 2 fields, one for the date and one for the time, is bound to a node which contains an `xs:dateTime` of the form `2010-11-12T10:16:36.209-08:00`. We'll need to go beyond this one component / one value mapping for components which can hold richer data, like the datatable.
2. What was said for binding in #1 extends to calling services. Form Builder doesn't put any restriction on what XML a service can return, but then Form Builder can just set the value of controls by extracting single values (not subtrees) from the XML returned by the service. This too will need to be extended to deal with richer components, like the datatable.
3. A first step is to support a read-only datatable. To support read-write datatable, certain cells will need to be able to contain other controls, making it more like the existing grid.

Comment: Thank you Alex; both for your wisdom and patience. I have successfully added the datatable component to the toolbox.  I can add it into a cell on a grid. At this point do I have to work with the code by hand adding repeat, tr, and td?  This is where my knowledge drops out.  I can't seem to make the connection between the database service and the datatable control.  Clearly the table needs to reference the "/testsvc/response/row" nodeset from the db service.

Comment: Bill, what you are aiming for is not straightforward, but very interesting. I added some ideas on supporting the datatable to my blurb above, under "Ideas about supporting the datatable".

Comment: Thank you Alex.  It seems you are saying datatables populated with repeating data is not possible in the current version of Orbeon.  Please let me know where this can go on your roadmap.

Comment: Bill, just to clarify, the datatable in Orbeon Forms *does* supports repeated rows. It is "just" that the datatable is not yet usable from Form Builder. If you need to use the datatable, I recommend you write your form "by hand", in XForms, instead of using Form Builder, if this is possible in your case. Does this make sense?